# How to connect to mongodb and How to print list of all collection from a dabase in mongodb using node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi I tried to connect to mongodb and print all collection from  a dabase in mongodb using node.js program but i am getting error. Code I tried is as below.

```
     var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://ipaddressofmywebsite:27017/databasename", function(err, db) {
      if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
         var  m = new MongoClient();
        var db = m.selectDB("databasename");
        var list= db.getCollectionNames();
        console.log(list);
      }
    });



        **I get the following error**


            throw err
                  ^
        TypeError: m.selectDB is not a function


When I tried the below code as suggested in this page also i get error.

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://websiteipaddress/databasename", 
    function(err, db) { // The db is passed in here.
      if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
        var list= db.getCollectionNames();
        console.log(list);
      }
    });



 **Error i get is**

        throw err
              ^

    TypeError: db.getCollectionNames is not a function
```

Kindly help me to fix this error

Comment: you already set databasename in the url, so you can delete the rows var  m = new MongoClient(); var db = m.selectDB("databasename"); You should use the db variable from the callback parameters

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to select a database. You already did that in the connection string: `mongodb://ipaddressofmywebsite:27017/databasename`. This should work:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://ipaddressofmywebsite:27017/databasename", 
    function(err, db) { // The db is passed in here.
      if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
        db.collectionNames(function(err, names) {
            console.log(names);
        });
      }
    });
```

[Here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/collections.html#list-existing-collections) is the docs for `MongoClient` - About getting the collection names

Comment: Hi I tried the solution but i am getting following error throw err
          ^

TypeError: db.getCollectionNames is not a function    I think I must make list also an array